# Istio Gateway minimum TLS version and allowed CipherSuites

Tags: kubernetes, networking, tls1.2, istio

I am trying to limit the TLS versions that can be used to TLS 1.2 and 1.3 and eliminate weak CipherSuites.
I made a few changes to the Istio Gateway but nothing worked so far.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  annotations: ...
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - hosts:
    - '*'
    port:
      name: http
      number: 80
      protocol: HTTP
    tls:
      httpsRedirect: true
  - hosts:
    - '*'
    port:
      name: http-for-tls-orig
      number: 443
      protocol: HTTP
    tls:
      cipherSuites:
      - ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
      - ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
      - ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305
      - ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305
      - ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
      - ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
      minProtocolVersion: TLSV1_2
```

Comment: How did you check that it did not work? Can you still call an endpoint behind this gateway on tls 1.1?

Comment: The output is missing, better add it to your question.

Comment: @Jeroen I tried several command ( namp / curl / openssl ...) and unfortunately it works for all of them. 
Last command was : `nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 443 [URL]`